XCM: messageQueue.Processed
I'm new to the world of Cross-Consensus Messaging (XCM). I'm trying to send an XCM message from Rococo AssetHub to Trappist to transfer funds from an asset that I've created on both chains, but I haven't been able to receive it in Trappist.
Here's the asset I created, with assetId (20240413) matching on both AssetHub and Trappist:


This is the XCM message I created on Rococo AssetHub using the limitedReserveTransferAssets function of the polkadotXcm pallet:



After submitting the extrinsic, this is what I received in Trappist:

The message did not show any error; it only states that the Success is No.
I would greatly appreciate it if someone could provide me with some guidance regarding my XCM. I'm curious if there might be an issue with it or if any configuration adjustments are needed prior to execution.
Thank you so much. 


The message did not show any error; it only states that the Success is No.

This basically tells you that there is an issue. Error reporting with XCM is currently not the best...
The best to debug this is to run one node at the receiving chain with -lxcm=trace. This will print trace logs that should hopefully give you a better understanding on the actual error.

Hi! I see, got it! Thank you so much.
